# Python: Should I version control .pem files?

Tags: python, version-control, pem

I was having some SSL connectivity issues while connecting to a secured URL, Later I fixed this problem by providing .pem file path for verifying. ie, `verify="file/path.pem"`

My doubt is should this file be stored in a common place on the server or should this file be part of the project source code and hence version control.

Please advise.

Comment: It depends a lot on what is in the pem file. Is it a private or a public key? (the header of the file should make it obvious)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most cases a `.pem` file contains sensitive information and is environment specific, it should not be part of the project source code. It should be available in a secured server and downloadable with appropriate authorization.